# Method recursion (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I ran into a perplex situation while I was trying to understand the binary search tree. I am baffled by the way the method recursion is happening here when a method is called, say `inOrder()`. Below is the code:

```
public class Node {
  int data;
  Node left;
  Node right;

public Node (int data) {
    this.data = data;
    left = null;
    right = null;
}
public Node() {
    left = null;
    right = null;
}
public int getData() {
    return data;
 }
}
====================
public class BinarySearch {
  Node root;

public BinarySearch() {
    root = null;
}
public void insert(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.data = data;
    if(root == null) {
        root = newNode;
        System.out.println("root =" + root.getData());
    } else {
        Node current = root;
        Node parent;
        while(true) {
            parent = current;
            if(data < current.data) {
                current = current.left;
                if(current == null){
                    parent.left = newNode;
                    break;
                }
        } else {
                current = current.right;
                if(current == null) {
                    parent.right = newNode;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public void inOrder() {
    inOrder(root);
}
private void inOrder(Node n) {
    if(n != null) {
        inOrder(n.left);
        System.out.print(n.getData() + " ");
        inOrder(n.right);
    }
  }
}
===================
 public class BTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      BinarySearch bst = new BinarySearch();
      bst.insert(10);
      bst.insert(4);
      bst.insert(11);
      bst.inOrder();
   }
}
o/p:
root = 10
4 10 11
```

Pardon me for the lengthy code, but I hoped you will need it complete.

When the `inOrder()` method is called, the compiler moves to the extreme `left` until `Node n` becomes `null` and exits the method based on the `if statement`, however, the immediate step the compiler is looking for after the `if` for `false` is `System.out.print(n.getData() + " ");` which is again inside the 'if' statement - This functionality amuses me a lot. I mean,

1) How is the compiler going to the line `System.out.print` when the `if` boolean is still `false`(because `Node n` is null) ?

2) Even if it goes to the print, how does `n.getData()` has a value(o/p: 4) when `Node n` actually reduced to `null`?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Please try a debugger, as it should help you understand how the stack unwinds.

Comment: Yes Elliott, after using the debugger only I ran into this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the Wang's answer. The java program pauses the execution of 4 (as you are recursively calling the method inOrder(4->left) i.e. inOrder(null).Now, it does not enter the condition as it fails).Now, the execution of 4 resumes and prints out the value 4 and then continues. I hope this helps.

Comment: ok, if it resumes, why should it execute the line `System.out.print(n.getData())` given above `if(n != null) {` as illustrated by Wang?

Comment: if the value of n is null, it won't enter the condition. The recursion uses stack(LIFO). It enters the line because the program has not completely executed for the value of 4. Hence, the next execution inOrder(4->left) is the print statement.

Comment: i meant the print statement above the `if(n != null)` (as Wang advised to use to verify the value inside n). I am wondering why it has to get executed when the compiler actually resumes at the next line it last stopped in the method.

Comment: It will execute only when there is a call for inOrder(node) method. The first  line before entering the condition if(n != null) is the print statement  Hence, it executes on every call to the method . So, when then there is null, the first statement before entering the condition  if(n != null)  throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: Thanks, your response helped :)

Answer (score 1):

So, when inOrder() hits the node "4" it invokes another inOrder() on the left node of the node "4", this time it's a null value, so it exits, and continues executing the inOrder() on node 4, prints the value of node 4, then invokes inOrder() again on the right side of the node which is -again- null, reaches the end of the function and returns back to the previous node.
also as Elliott Frisch said: try a debugger to understand the method's stack.

Answer (score 1):

The program doesn't go to the line System.out.print if it's going into an empty left node. The BST that your program has assembled has 10 as the root, 4 as the left branch of the root, and 11 as the right branch of the root. When inOrder() is called, after going to the left branch onto node.data=4, the program then attempts to look at the left branch of the node.data=4. That left branch is null, so the value of 4 is printed.

You can verify this by placing

```
System.out.print(n.getData() + " ");
```

above

```
if(n != null) {
```

And you'll encounter an exception.

Comment: yes, my point - how is the program skipping the `if` check?(as `n` is null ) and going into `if` block to execute `System.out.print(n.getData() + "  ");`?

Comment: It's not skipping the if check. To verify this, put in some print statements before the if statement, and you'll see that the if statement isn't being skipped. Or better yet, add a if (n==null) statement in inOrder() with a print statement.